# High CPU usage for Windows Error Reporting Service on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-services, windows-error-reporting, windows-insider, high-cpu-usage

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 Version 2004, via the Slow Ring of the Windows Insiders programme. About a day later, I noticed that my computer is significantly slowed down and things like right-clicking on folders (but not files) takes a very long time. I checked the running processes and sure enough, the Windows Error Reporting Service was frequently consuming between 30-100% of my CPU:

[image]

What is this issue caused by, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Whenever I had strange delays in I/O actions, it was nearly always explain, by the fact my mechanical HDD was starting to fail.  The fact the service in question is consuming a large amounts of CPU resources indicates there is indeed a legitimate error happening.

Comment: @Ramhound What does high CPU have to do with I/O? The disk usage is next to nothing, and even if it were high, the chances of it being a dying disk directly after a Windows 10 upgrade are slim.

Comment: I was just sharing my experience.  I specifically recall symptoms surrounding my mouse, when my HDD was in a failing status.  I would perform an action, and 20-30 seconds, the action would happen.  This would behavior would be random, most of the time, the computer worked flawlessly.  SFC and DISM would report no errors.

Comment: I just finished reinstalling my Test Machine.  V2004 19591.1001.  It is operating normally (as it did before) and CPU is running under 5%

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little I've been able to find on this I'm assuming that this is a fairly new bug exclusive to Insiders, and with error reporting not being particularly useful for the day-to-day operation of my system I decided the best way to deal with it would be to disable the Error Reporting Service until the bug has been resolved.

[Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/how-do-i-disable-error-reporting-in-windows-2626074) offers a detailed tutorial to do so for anyone with little technical experience, but for everyone else, a more concise version is:

1. Open `services.msc` from the search bar
2. Search for the Windows Error Reporting Service" and double-click it
3. Change its startup type to Disabled, and apply the changes

EDIT: Although this solution fixes the high CPU usage, the very slow right-click on folders is still present, so it seems that this is a separate bug.

Comment: I did not see this on my Test Machine.  Try running DISM and SFC (both).  From an admin command prompt, run  dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by sfc /scannow  . When complete, restart and test

Comment: "Although this solution fixes the high CPU usage, the very slow right-click on folders is still present, so it seems that this is a separate bug." - This indicates an I/O problem.  I have experienced similar behavior when mechanical HDDs were in a failed or failing state.  I also have not experienced this on any current or recent build of `Windows 10 version 2004`.

Comment: @John `sfc` flagged no problems and `dism` didn't either. I'm getting a lot of very weird errors right now that suggest malware, or that Windows 10 is behaving like malware, so I'm going to restore to a last working image and take it slow to see whether this issue crops up again and if so, what causes it.

Comment: Try that and also run a complete full scan with Windows Defender. I am in the middle of re-loading my Test Laptop (nothing to do with the above issue) and that should be done later today. I will keep watch.

Comment: @John One of the malware-like problems is that Defender actually keeps on disabling itself. At first I thought this was due to having MalwareBytes running alongside it, but even removing MB, Defender refuses to turn on and Windows Update refuses to run. Will report back based on what I experience after the re-image.

Comment: Maybe try removing  Malwarebytes temporarily. I rely solely on Windows Defender and it stays running at all times.

Comment: Did removing Malwarebytes help?  Did you re-image?  and then what?

Comment: @John I re-imaged and have spent the last few days redoing the changes at a slower pace to gradually rule each one out. The issue hasn't reproduced yet so at this point I think it's highly likely to be the fact that Defender and MalwareBytes weren't playing well together. I'll be re-installing MalwareBytes soon to confirm.

Comment: Also V2004 is now at 19603.1000 (new yesterday). Let us know how it all goes.